# How to use Skiplocation when im using canDeactive

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm using skipLocation and canDeactivate in my project. If my page got refresh I used canDeactive to show popup whether to continue or move if I give No my url is changed into original url skipLocation is not working.

My Guard Service: here I call `dialogService` whether to proceed or exit.

```
  canDeactivate(component: any, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    if (!component.isUpdating) {
      component.isUpdating = false;
      console.log(currentState.url,'sss')
      return this.dialogService.confirm('Discard changes for Country?',currentState.url);
    }
    return true;
  }
```

This is my service if i give yes to redirect. SkipLocation working perfectly without append orginal path to url. If i proceed with No it exist in same page but orginal path is showing in url. skipLocation is not working.

```
export class CanDeactivateService {
  constructor(private modelService: NgbModal,private router : Router){

  }
  confirm(message?: string,url?){
    const subject = new Subject<boolean>();
    let confirmation = false;
    const modelRef = this.modelService.open(DeactivateRouteComponent,{
      size: 'lg',
      backdrop: false
    });
    modelRef.componentInstance.subject = subject;
    modelRef.componentInstance.closeBox.subscribe(resp=>{
      if(!resp){
        modelRef.close();
      }
    })
    return subject.asObservable();
  };
}
```

Comment: any code snippet ?

Comment: It can be that the problem is with your `this.dialogService.confirm` function. Is it returning an *Observable* / *Promise*?

Comment: Ya Observable
{
  "_isScalar": false,
  "source": {
    "_isScalar": false,
    "observers": [],
    "closed": false,
    "isStopped": false,
    "hasError": false,
    "thrownError": null
  }
}

Comment: Try to replace this code with a simple return of `false` value and see if the problem still exists. Now it looks like the problem is with `this.modelService.open` function.

Comment: I removed the model and changed to return false not working my path get changed